# PHP/FPDF keep loading behind cloudflare

Tags: php, fpdf, cloudflare

i have a problem with cloudflare.
My web app uses FPDF (PHP) to generate PDF files, but when i activate clouflare, the PDF generates only once, when i reload the pdf it does not load anymore, it is like still loading in the pdf viewer but in the network console say a status code 200.

The solution i found now is to disable cloudflare and use it as "DNS Only" mode, but i want to use cloudflare in my site, any idea why is tis happening?

PHP 5.6
Apache 2

I tried to create page rules for that domain disabling everything but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after so much try.

The trick was creating a page rule with this pattern: `https://*.example.com/*pdf*` (all my generated PDFS has `pdf` in their routes) and disable this items

- Auto Minify = All Off
- Always Online = Off
- Cache Level = Bypass

[image: cloudflare rules]
After this, wait some minutes or hours to the changes being applied.